# Phoenix string interpolation containing \n and name="abc" in HTML

Tags: phoenix-framework

I want to generate HTML content in phoenix. I'm not able to use interpolation while adding `name="abc"`. I get an error at `"`.

Using `\` in text also shows the `\`, e.g. `text = "This is an name=\"abc\" string"` gives `text = "This is an name=\"abc\" string"`.

Can anyone please suggest how I can have a raw string containing `name="abc"`?

Answer (score 1):

The string does contain only `name="abc"`, the problem is that when you see it in the terminal, Elixir escapes the double quotes, so you can copy and paste it to your code. If in doubt, use `IO.puts(text)`, and it will print the text without doing any changes to it:

```
iex(1)> text = "This is an name=\"abc\" string"
"This is an name=\"abc\" string"
iex(2)> IO.puts text
This is an name="abc" string
:ok
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interpolate some double quotes into a string, you might try this:

```
iex(1)> text = "This is a name=#{"abc"} string"
"This is a name=abc string"
```

That didn't work.  You need to do something extra:

```
iex(16)> text = "This is a name=#{"\"abc\""} string"
"This is a name=\"abc\" string"
```

When you write something like this:

```
text = "This is a name="abc" string"
```

You should wonder how is it that elixir knows that the last quote is the quote that terminates the string.  In other words, why doesn't elixir think that this is your string:

```
text = "This is a name="
```

and the rest of the line is just garbage that doesn't follow elixir's syntax?  In order to tell elixir that the double quote after the `=` sign is not the end of the string--but that it's just another character within the string--you ***escape*** the double quote, like this:

```
text = "This is a name=\"abc\" string"
```

Now, elixir will see the double quote after ***string*** as the termination of the string.

Next, it is a complete hassle to escape double quotes within a string, so elixir provides a means of avoiding that with the `~s` sigil:

```
iex(17)> text = ~s{This is a name="abc" string}
"This is a name=\"abc\" string"
```

With the `~s` sigil, you can use various character pairs to surround your string, e.g. `()` or `<>` or `| |` or `/ /`.  You need to use a character pair that is not found within the string--otherwise you will run into the same problem as with interior double quotes.

Finally, you can prove that the string `name=\"abc\"` has only 10 characters, i.e. the characters `name="abc"`, like this:

```
iex(13)> s1 = ~s{name="abc"}
"name=\"abc\""

iex(14)> String.length s1
10
```